# I want to display the entire list of countries in the Select Options menu in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to display the entire list of countries in the Select Options menu in laravel.

**this my data :**
[this my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfn1X.jpg)

**this the controller**

public function getCart()

```
        {
            $country = Roketin::country()->list()->get();
            // dd($country);
            $province = Roketin::province()->list('country_code')->get();
            // dd($province);
            $carts = Cart::getContent();
            return view('pay-viewcart', compact('carts', 'country', 'province'));
        }
```

**this my blade.php**

*COUNTRY

```
    <select class="selectpicker" id="country" name="country">
          <option> -- Select One -- </option>
                  @foreach($country->data[0]->name as $countries)
                          <option> {{$countries}} </option>   
                  @endforeach                                            
     </select>
```

and error :
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: D:\PPI\projek-1\savanacamp\resources\views\pay-viewcart.blade.php)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="country" name="country">
    <option> -- Select One -- </option>
    @foreach($country->data as $item)
        <option> {{$item->name}} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

or

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="country" name="country">
    <option> -- Select One -- </option>
    @foreach($country->data as $item)
        <option> {{$item['name']}} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I change this, and there is and error "Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\PPI\projek-1\savanacamp\resources\views\pay-viewcart.blade.php)"

Comment: change {{$item->name}} to {{$item['name']}}

Comment: and may be you need to use: @foreach($country->data as $item) or @foreach($country['data'] as $item)

Comment: if I try this `@foreach($country['data'] as $item)` .
error :
"Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed supplying wrong values in the `foreach`

Update your foreach as follows.

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="country" name="country">
    <option> -- Select One -- </option>
    @foreach($country as $c)
    <!--        ^--- supply the list here.  -->
        <option> {{ $c->data[0]->name }} </option>   
    <!--                   ^--- access the name here -->
    @endforeach                                               
</select>
```

Comment: I change this, and there is and error 
"Trying to get property of non-object (View: D:\PPI\projek-1\savanacamp\resources\views\pay-viewcart.blade.php)"

Comment: update the accessing of the name, because I dont have any idea how your models look like. or how `$country` array/list looks like. please `dd` it and see for yourself. The main problem we want to answer here is your wrong construction of foreach. Either update your question for us to have an updated information of your problem or look through those errors and try to find where you had a mistake. :)

Comment: the data array listed above in my question. the format is image